# Kill the overutilized [utilization] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

13 questions are currently tagged [utilization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utilization) (I removed the tag from [one other question](https://superuser.com/q/343677/53590)).

- How to find maximum amount of requests for a file with a certain utilization percent?
- elasticsearch + kibana: disk usage grows over day
- How to track Mac computer utilization throughout my organization?
- Probook 4520s CPU hangs at 100% and 199MHz? any ideas
- Does a Windows service priority change really allocate so more CPU utilization for that service?
- Windows 8 extremely high disk usage and slow IO
- Disk utilization 100%, no read or write
- How to get CPU %user %system in FreeBSD without using top?
- Calculating Utilization in a Stop-And-Wait Protocol
- CPU and HD degradation on sourced based Linux distribution
- Is There A Way To Calculate Data In Task Manager?
- Spurious high disk IOrate alerts from remote server
- Force an application to use 90% of the cpu, mac

The tag:

- doesn't seem to add anything concrete in terms of categorization
- isn't used coherently, as illustrated above
- has no followers
- has no tag wiki
- is pretty hard to be a subject matter expert in

I propose **we kill the `utilization` tag.**

Comment: Eh, only 13? Seems like a 5 mins task....

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, its a classic meta tag.

We can get rid of it.